# Java project imported from github not recognized by IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, maven, github, intellij-idea

I've recently imported a project from github on a different computer and it doesn't seem to work.

Things I've tried or checked so far:

- my jdk is set
- the folders are marked (src, test, etc..)
- maven clean/build/install work properly
- pom shows no error
- Java home env variable set
- restarted the ide
- re-downloaded the project
- rebuilt the project

i'm adding a couple of screenshots based on the feedback that you provided. Tell me if i can provide any more info.

[folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtQKD.png)

[pom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30FDM.png)

[sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTLnC.png)

[image: example of errors shown in the code]

Comment: Import it is a Maven project, you seem to have imported it as a java project and tried to shoehorn the directories into source folders for the IDE.

Comment: There's no real way to help with the info provided. Generally speaking if you open a project directory and there's nothing particularly custom about the directory layout it'll just work. It'd depend how you opened/imported it.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot that shows that the JDK is set. for now it looks as if that is one of the problems. Then please check if all dependencies are working.

Comment: Never need JAVA_HOME to be set.  I never use it.  Which version of IntelliJ?  Review your project settings.  I'd bet those are not correct.

Comment: @duffymo IntelliJ version in 2021.3

Comment: @DaveNewton tell me what info should i provide

Comment: @M.Deinum file > new > project from VCS 

it's not the first time i try to clone a repo on intellij like this

Comment: What did you mark the `src` folder as? Yes, `src/main/java` should be marked, but IDEA should do that itself when you open a maven project. Don't mark any directories yourself.

Comment: But it's not new, it exists. File -> Open the directory containing the project.

Comment: @FOCS People downvote for a variety of reasons, including lack of information, a perceived lack of effort, etc. Who knows. I'd recommend spending a bit more time w/ IJ trying to figure it out--it's pretty much open-and-play for standard Maven projects.

Comment: You state "maven clean/build/install work properly", what about `mvn clean compile`? Try making sure this maven goal is run through the IDE (you can double-tap <Shift>, enter "execute maven goal", then enter "clean compile"). You can also attempt to "Run" your main class afterwards, _even though there's errors_. IntelliJ sometimes gets stuck believing it cannot build something until it actually is just forced to attempt the build.

Comment: @Rogue If `maven clean` and `maven install` works doesn't that imply `maven clean compile` would work? IJ isn't going to do much of anything if it doesn't think the app's own source is in the right place.

Comment: When I open a maven project, I do not select the project folder but instead selecting the pom.xml (at top-level)

Comment: @Rogue i've tried your suggestion, maven clean compile works fine. i've tried to run my spring application class and it says "the output path is not configured" on a popup message. On the same popup it is possible to click on "configure" and if i do so it brings me to the SDK dialog (see screenshot above)

Comment: Your IntelliJ is two years behind, but that does not explain your problem.  SO isn't a good forum to review what you need to do with IntelliJ.  Go through each of the project settings and make sure they are correct.  What JDK are you using?  Is that available to IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took my source code and created a new project from scratch. Everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to perform the following steps:

- `File | Repair IDE`
- `File | Invalidate Caches... | Invalidate and Restart`
- `File | Close Project` and close the IDE
- Open the project root directory in the OS file explorer and delete all `.iml` files and the `.idea` folder
- Re-import your project in IntelliJ by selecting `pom.xml` file

Comment: i've done steps 1-4 

for what concerns step 5, just to be clear, i should download it from github and then try to import the project by selecting the pom?

Comment: Ideally you would `git clone <your github URL>` in the directory you want the project, then in IntelliJ you would `File` > `Open` > select the `pom.xml` in the cloned repo.

Comment: Or just open the directory.

Comment: @Rogue done that. Everything stays the same. I'm wondering i haven't committed some indispensable files.

Comment: Did you commit the `.idea/` folder? If so, delete that, then re-import the project.